# Socket.io connecting to another Domain error

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im currently running my own website using socket.io in nodejs.
My problem was that Im using cloudflare and all opened ports were already in use so I decided to buy an additional IP address to my current VPS.

Now I need to connect the socket.io connection to a different sub domain which redirect to my additional IP address.
The sub domain is already connected to the ip and the ip successfully redirect to the domain.

Im connecting my socket connection like this:

`server.listen(socket_port, 'https://sub.my-domain.com');`

sub.my-domain is my actual sub-domain.

Now when Im starting my nodejs app Im getting that error:
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://sub.my-domain.com`

Anyone know why Im getting this and is able to help?
Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://sub.my-domain.com`. I would suggest you to try to put an `IP address` instead of `https://sub.my-domain.com`or try only `sub.my-domain.com`or something like `http://sub.my-domain.com`. Obviously the server can't connect to the domain address you have specified.

Comment: Thats the error Im getting when entering the ip
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL my-ip-address:port

Comment: are you putting the machine's ip address in there? you can get it from https://tell-my-ip.com or maybe try your local ip that starts with `192.168..`, try them both, let me know

Comment: I have put in the additional IP address of my VPS.
So yeah basically the ip address of it

Comment: I don't know, maybe it has to do with buying a new IP and using it as for the reason you have specified. I think so since you have tried all the algorithms that might work. There must be configurations to it.